# android - Getting the handle for child views from custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have create a Java class extending `LinearLayout` as shown below

```
         public class CustomLinear extends LinearLayout{

        Context context;

         public CustomLinear(Context context) {
        super(context);
          this.context=context;

         ViewFlipper viewFlipper=new ViewFlipper(context);
         viewFlipper.setLayoutParams(this.getLayoutParams());
        this.addView(viewFlipper);

        }
```

And included the custom built layout into my Main.xml as shown below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.android.apis"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



              <com.homevito.customlayout.CustomLinear
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/alerts"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And in my MainActivity i'm using main.xml as content view as follows:

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {



         /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


        }
    }
```

I want to handle the `viewFlipper` from the `MainActivity`. I tried setting Id for `viewFlipper` but still dint help...

How can I get to handle the `viewflipper`.. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: public News(Context context) should be changed to public CustomLinear (Context context)

Comment: well sorry for that typo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you use your custom component in a xml layout you'll need the second constructor implemented(the one that takes a `Context`, `AttributeSet`). 
Second of all you could add a getter method for your `ViewFlipper`:

```
public class CustomLinear extends LinearLayout{

        Context context;
        private ViewFlipper mFlipper;

        public CustomLinear(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
             super(context, attrs);
             this.context=context;
             mFlipper = new ViewFlipper(context);
             mFlipper.setLayoutParams(this.getLayoutParams());
             this.addView(mFlipper);
        }

      // the getter method
      public ViewFlipper getTheFlipper() {
           return mFlipper;
      }
```

Then in your activity you could simple do:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
CustomLinear cl = (CustomLinear) findViewById(R.id.one);
ViewFlipper flipperReference = cl.getTheFlipper();
```

Comment: If u dont mind can u please tell me the need for the third attribute in the constructor.

Comment: @vivek Sorry it's the constructor that takes an `AttributeSet` besides the `Context`. This is required because you use the custom component in the xml layout and those `AttributeSet` come from the xml attributes(like android:background="@drawable/alerts"). The constructor that takes a `Context` is used when you instantiate directly the custom view in code.

Comment: Oh yes this I understand ... Got confused with the third attribute (int i) in your previous post.... :D

Answer (score 2):

Try following snippet

```
class CustomLinear extends LinearLayout {

    private Context context;

    public CustomLinear(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;

        ViewFlipper viewFlipper = new ViewFlipper(context);
        viewFlipper.setId(1234);
        viewFlipper.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        this.addView(viewFlipper);

    }
```

and in onCreate()

```
CustomLinear customLinear = (CustomLinear) findViewById(R.id.one);

ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) customLinear.findViewById(1234);
```

Comment: Okay Shah i tried this... But i did not use the customLinear 's object.. Will try this right away